# Get header from HttpUrlConnection object

Tags: java, http

I want to send request to servlet and read headers from response. So I try it using this:

```
  URL url = new URL(contextPath + "file_operations");
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 5);
        conn.connect();

        conn.getHeaderField("MyHeader")
        .....
```

But received headers are always `null`. Servlet works fine (i tried work with servlet using standalone HTTP client)

Comment: Is it connecting or giving any exception ??

Answer (score 42):

Make sure you are getting the successful response before you try to fetch the headers. This is how you can check for your response:

```java
int status = conn.getResponseCode();

if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    String header = conn.getHeaderField("MyHeader");
}
```

Also make sure the Servlet response is not a redirect response, if redirected all the session information, including headers will be lost.

Answer (score 16):

Before the connect (right after setRquestPropert, setDoOutput a.s.o):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entries : conn.getRequestProperties().entrySet()) {    
    String values = "";
    for (String value : entries.getValue()) {
        values += value + ",";
    }
    Log.d("Request", entries.getKey() + " - " +  values );
}
```

Before disconnect (after reading response a.s.o):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entries : conn.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
    String values = "";
    for (String value : entries.getValue()) {
        values += value + ",";
    }
    Log.d("Response", entries.getKey() + " - " +  values );
}
```